# reading .wav files in python

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying (for a course) to read a sound file .wav via ipython. When I try the 'normal' code to read a file:

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read

(fs,x) = read ('/Users/joehigham/Desktop/Audio_1.wav')
```

I get the well known traceback call of

```
ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this happens, and of course how can I right the problem?

Thanks in advance - I did look round SO for the solution, but nothing (that I found) seems to match this problem with sound files.

Comment: I thought I should add ... could this be something to do with the sampling rate of a file (24bits, etc)?

Comment: Either way file is not valid or you need to update scipy

Comment: I tried `pip install --upgrade scipy` and got
`Requirement already up-to-date: scipy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wav file probably has 24 bit data.  You can check with:

```
import wave
w = wave.open("filename.wav")
print(w.getsampwidth())
```

If the value printed is 3, your data is 24 bit.  If that is the case, `scipy.io.wavfile` won't work.  I wrote a reader that handles 24 bit data; see https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/wavio (which replaced the gist at <strike>https://gist.github.com/WarrenWeckesser/7461781</strike>).  The reader is also [on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wavio).

Comment: Indeed it is! I just tried a wave file from Audacity and so far so good. I'll update my answer in a minute, this way it will save others trying to solve a solved problem. Thanks for the information.